# Use common JS libs inside sandboxed iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox, postmessage

I plan to build a module system for my webapp that uses sandboxed iframes and the postMessage API to securely run custom user modules. The iframe blocks all DOM access and should only communicate through an interface provided by me which checks some permissions and provides data.

The system itself is very simple and works fine with vanilla js code inside the modules, however I want to allow developers to use common frameworks/libs to ease development, i.e. by using Vue for data binding.

What is the best way to provide such functionality to the modules? Performance is a huge factor since several dozens of such modules might run at the same time. Is it secure to let sandboxed modules share libs?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem correctly. Should every module be loaded as an iframe and the host page should be able to control all modules via `postMesage`?

Comment: @Gambo Exactly, that's how I have implemented it so far but now I want to provide libs to the sandboxes

Answer (score 5):

**Good advice:** Unfortunately, `iframe` sandboxing goes both ways. In general (with a few exceptions: mainly `postMessage` and [pages that satisfy the same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)), an `iframe` is effectively a separate webpage and cannot be accessed from the host page, and vice-versa. It's probably a better alternative to just request that the individual developers use lightweight libraries.

**Bad advice:** If you hosted the other devs' files yourself, they could access each other, but having stuff accessible between `iframe`s in this way is certainly not ideal- and doing it this way is a *really* bad idea, as it exposes you to all sorts of scripting-related attacks; not to mention the fact that the separate `iframe`s would probably accidentally interfere with one another in unexpected ways if you shared Javascript variables between them. **Don't do it this way** unless you *explicitly* trust every single developer here to behave properly and code well (i.e. you're in the same workplace). Actually, just don't do it this way at all.

If you really really want to do this, though: an `iframe` whose target is hosted on the same website can access its parent page through the global variable `parent` (i.e. `parent` in an `iframe` is the same as `window` in the host, `parent.$` would be the parent's jQuery object, and `parent.document.getElementById` is the same as `document.getElementById`). A parent page can access its same-origin `iframe`s with `document.getElementById("the id of the iframe").contentWindow` (and `.contentWindow.document`, etc. will work here too), but again, if you hosted the code of potentially-malicious developers on your page to get around the same-origin policy, **you'd be giving these developers access to your page and any information, including passwords, that your users type on it.**

Comment: Since my app should run untrusted code it is definitly not an option to expose the parent window, that's why I want to use sandboxed iframes to avoid same-origin access. Therefore I will probably go with the good advice, thanks for your opinion!